# C++ generic insert into std container?

Tags: c++, c++11, containers

If I have the following program:

```
#include <vector>
#include <set>

template<class T, class U>
void AddToContainer(T& container, U value)
{
  container.push_back(value);
}

int main(char**, int)
{
   std::vector<int> v;
   AddToContainer(v, 1);

   std::set<int> s;
   AddToContainer(s, 1);

   return 0;
}
```

How can I make the adding to the container generic? Since `std::set` hasn't got a `push_back` but only `insert`, this will fail to compile.

Comment: This is one of those things that *sound* like a good idea, but in practice never is.

Comment: the STL already has about as much *static polymorphism* as is sensible - after all , it's one of the design goals. What you propose is simply going to encourage clients of your `AddToContainer` to be inefficient.

Answer (score 11):

You could use expression SFINAE with a dummy parameter to check if `push_back()` works:

```
template <class C, class V>
auto append(C& container, V&& value, int)
    -> decltype(container.push_back(std::forward<V>(value)), void())
{
    container.push_back(std::forward<V>(value));
}

template <class C, class V>
void append(C& container, V&& value, ...)
{
    container.insert(std::forward<V>(value));
}
```

which your function will just forward to:

```
template <class C, class V>
void AddToContainer(C& container, V&& value) {
    append(container, std::forward<V>(value), 0);
}
```

If `push_back()` is a valid expression, the first overload will be preferred since `int` is a better match for `0` than `...` If `push_back()` isn't a valid expression, then there's only one viable overload.

---

Whether this is actually a good idea or not is a separate question.

Comment: One can probably just use insert-with-`end()` in both cases.

Comment: @T.C. What does that actually mean for `std::set` if the hint is bad?

Comment: Slightly less efficient. It's the same complexity as unhinted insert, but you'll probably pay an extra comparison.

Comment: You should add the insert-with-end() as an answer its far less complicated than this, plus this answer needs some C++17 stuff (tagged C++11)

Comment: @paulm This answer doesn't need any C++17 stuff.

Comment: @paulm Trailing return type was introduced in C++11. [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=1cc35eb0591798ca)

Answer (score 7):

I believe that all* C++ containers (though not the container adapters like `priority_queue`) have a version of insert that looks like this:

```cpp
iterator insert(iterator location, T&& value)
```

For the sequence collections, the location is the actual location; for associative collections (like `map` and `unordered_map`), the iterator is a "hint" parameter (for instance, to help a `map` insert an element quickly if you already know precisely where it belongs in sorted order). However, providing an invalid hint doesn't cause any invalid behavior, so a valid generic insert for C++ collections would be:

```cpp
template<C, T>
void insert(C& collection, T&& value) {
    collection.insert(collection.end(), std::forward<T>(value));
}
```

* It looks like `forward_list` is the only one that doesn't have this method, which makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

C++20 style:

```
template<typename C, typename V>
  requires requires (C& c, V&& v) { c.push_back(std::forward<V>(v)); }
auto AddToContainer(C& container, V&& value) {
  return container.push_back(std::forward<V>(value));
}

template<typename C, typename V>
  requires (requires (C& c, V&& v) { c.insert(c.end(), std::forward<V>(v)); } &&
    !requires(C& c, V&& v) { c.push_back(std::forward<V>(v)); })
auto AddToContainer(C& container, V&& value) {
  return container.insert(container.end(), std::forward<V>(value));
}
```

or more succinct but with worse diagnostics:

```
template<typename C, typename V>
auto AddToContainer(C& container, V&& value)
{
  if constexpr (requires (C& c, V&& v) { c.push_back(std::forward<V>(v)); })
    return container.push_back(std::forward<V>(value));

  else
    return container.insert(container.end(), std::forward<V>(value));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is already one (`#include <iterator>`), but it has weird syntax:

```
std::inserter(container, container.end()) = value;
```

All this does is use [Lucretiel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61847474/3601660) under the hood, which still has problems with `forward_list` lacking an `insert` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you are **not** worried about the order of elements inserted in the set,

```
template<typename Container, typename value>
void addelement(Container& C, value v)
{
    std::fill_n(std::inserter(C,C.end()), 1,v);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    addelement(v, 2);
    addelement(v, 4);
    addelement(v, 6);

    std::set<int> s;
    addelement(s, 8);
    addelement(s, 6);
    addelement(s, 4);
    addelement(s, 8);

    std::cout << "Vector elements :: " << std::endl;
    for (auto item : v)
        std::cout << item << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Set elements :: " << std::endl;
    for (auto item : s)
        std::cout << item << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```